# how to create a dynamic form backend in flutter

Tags: flutter, forms, dart, hybrid-mobile-app, dart-null-safety

[This is my backend data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PdJd.png)

[This is my form screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKwap.png)

how can I get the control value of these dynamic fields

```
class DyDataList with ChangeNotifier {
  final List<DyData> _dyDataList = [
    DyData(
      filedName: "Full Name",
      control: "TextBox",
      source: "",
      hintText: "e.g John ",
      contolValue: "",
    ),
DyData(
  filedName: "Age",
  control: "TextBox",
  source: "",
  hintText: "e.g 18",
  contolValue: "",
),
```

This is my FormScreen

```
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text("Form"),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: dyData.length,
            itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
              value: dyData[i],
              child: WidControls(
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

I need these controller values on submit button

Answer (score -1):

You must create `TextEditingController` for each `TextFormField` and after that when you receive data from your back you can put your data on your `TextFormField` something like this:

first create this:

```
  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
```

After that put your `TextEditingController` into the your

```
    TextFormField(
      controller: nameController,
    )
```

finally when you got your data from your back, put your data into the `TextEditingController` like this:

```
nameController.text = "your data";
```

Comment: I think this solution is for a simple textfiled but in my case how I can use this TextEditingController dynamically for each  TextField